# iOS "reduce transparency" option on iPhone

Tags: alpha, ios7.1, translucency

Is there a way to get the new iOS 7.1 option "reduce transparency" activated in the simulator? Does anybody now where I can find substantial information about the new option and how it actually works in iOS 7.1?

I have the wired problems:

1. to have no effects on changing the color alpha value for my toolbar in the simulator. It is always bright and not translucent. I have set alpha of `setBarTintColor` to 0.5 and `setTranslucent:YES`.
2. on the iPhone when I switch on the option "reduce transparency" the toolbar is actually translucent! BUT when I switch off the option the toolbar is opaque. What do I get wrong? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

I really try to understand the new changes on the design but I do not find any answers somewhere.
Thanks